# What steps do I take to calculate

Tags: probability

> Let $\bar{x}$ denote the mean of a random sample of size $80$ from the 
>    distribution whose pdf is:
>    $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^3}{4} &\text{if $0 < x < 2$} \\
>             0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
>    Find $P(1.5 ≤ \bar{x} ≤ 1.65)$

I don't want the answer, I just want to know how to get the values for $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.  If I understand how to get those values, then I think I can complete the problem on my own.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic approach.**  Use the normal approximation.  If you know the mean $\mu$ and the variance $\sigma^2$ of the distribution given by that PDF, then the mean of the random sample will also be $\mu$, but its variance will be given by $\frac{\sigma^2}{80}$.  Use those parameters to convert $1.5$ and $1.65$ into their corresponding $z$-values $z_1$ and $z_2$, respectively.  Then

$$
P(1.5 \leq \overline{x} \leq 1.65) = P(z \leq z_2) - P(z \leq z_1)
$$

Use your favorite calculator for $z$-values.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean when you say to use those parameters to convert 1.5 and 1.65 into their corresponding values.  How would I use those parameters?

Comment: @obsolutemal: To pick a simpler example, suppose you had a distribution with mean $2$ and variance $0.25$.  Then the standard deviation would be $0.5$.  The value $1.5$ is $1$ standard deviation below the mean, so its corresponding $z$-value would be $-1$.  The value $1.65$ is $0.7$ standard deviations below the mean, so its corresponding $z$-value would be $-0.75$.  Do the same, but with the actual mean and variance/standard deviation of the sample mean for the actual PDF provided.

Comment: How do we know 1.5 is 1 standard deviation below the mean and 1.65 is 0.7 standard deviations below the mean?  If it's .7, don't we do -.7 and not -.75?  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @obsolutemal: Oops, yes I meant $0.7$ in both cases.  (Unfortunately, I can no longer edit that comment.)  In the case of $1.65$, it is just $\frac{1.65-2}{0.5} = -0.7$.  Similarly for $1.5$.